# Is there a way to count number of appearances (nested list) using Counter

Tags: python, list, dictionary, hash, counter

I have a nested list and there are duplicates inside. I want to get each list content and its corresponding appearances. So for nested list I have:

```
nested_list = [['time', 'company', 'language', 'price', 'description'],
               ['date', 'language', 'price', 'quantity'],
               ['time', 'company', 'language', 'price', 'description'],
               ['quantity', 'time', 'date', description']]
```

I used `nested_list.sort()` and it gave:

```
['date', 'language', 'price', 'quantity']
['quantity', 'time', 'date', 'description']
['time', 'company', 'language', 'price', 'description']
['time', 'company', 'language', 'price', 'description']
```

So the general sort works fine if I want the same item (list) to be placed together. But how can I get each's appearance? Should I iterate through the whole list and use a dictionary to record each nested list's content (string value, I'm sure I once read something online saying that list is not good to be used as dictionary key value) and count its appearance?

The plain `collections.Counter` can't be used because `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'` (another reason using a dictionary a bad idea, if list used as hash key).

Is there a way to do it? Should I extract the string values within each nested list and use the long string as key?

Comment: Note that you *can* hash a `tuple`... Note also that *"list is not good to be used as dictionary key value"* **because** you can't hash a list - dictionary keys must be immutable, which lists are not, so it's not just *"not good"* it's not allowed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert each list to a tuple first:

```
from collections import Counter

counts = Counter(tuple(el) for el in nested_list)
#Counter({('time', 'company', 'language', 'price', 'description'): 2, ('quantity', 'time', 'date', 'description'): 1, ('date', 'language', 'price', 'quantity'): 1})
```

Comment: got to use Counter eventually ;)

Comment: @PadraicCunningham you should really join us in [python chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6/python) now and again :)